# Bluetoothctl scan not showing Apple devices?

Tags: bluetooth

When running Bluetoothctl scan on or scan le on my lububtu machine (Bluetooth 4.0). I get lots of hits for Bluetooth addresses, but I can’t seem to find my iPad or iPhone though.

I have run a Bluetooth finder on my iPhone and it has no problem discovering Apple devices. My bluez is up to date as well.